# Python CLI: print 'some text' vs 'some text'

Tags: python

Why does `>>> 'c\\\h'` produces `'c\\\\h'`  via the python CLI

But `>>> print 'c\\\h'` produces `c\\h`

Comment: `>>> 'c\\\h'` doesn't produce `c\\\\h`. It produces `'c\\\\h'`.

Comment: @BhargavRao No way, this question is more general; the title reflects that.

Comment: @interjay doesn't answer the question though .. it still produces 4 backslashes

Comment: It was a correction to your question, not an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Python interpreter running in REPL mode prints [representation (`repr` builtin)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr) of result of last statement (it it exists and not a `None`):

```
>>> 5 + 6
11
```

For `str` objects representation is a [string literal](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) in a same form it is written in your code (except for the quotes that may differ), so it includes escape sequences:

```
>>> '\n\t1'
'\n\t1'
>>> print repr('\n\t1')
'\n\t1'
```

`print` statement (or function) on the other hand prints [pretty string-conversion (`str` builtin)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) of an element, which makes all escape sequences being converted to actual characters:

```
>>> print '\n\t1'
                           <---- newline
    1                      <---- tab + 1
```

Comment: what i got from your explanation is that..repr() displays the string just as it is, but print() function formats it... does't explain the extra/deducted backslashes using the examples i provided though

Comment: @Emmanuel: _format_ is incorrect term here. Like I said, it _replaces escape sequences_. I.e. `'\n'` -> newline. For backslashes: `'\\'` -> single backslash. That is why backslashes doubled in `repr` (see string literal link in my post)